# Как мне код отдельного коммита запустить?

Tags: php

Как мне код отдельного коммита запустить?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `checkout` на нужный коммит

Answer (score 1):

```
git checkout commit_hash
```

commit_hash - вместо него поставьте хеш своего коммита. После этого head перейдет на этот коммит. Когда все проверите, вернуться на последнюю версию кода можно также, сделав

```
git checkout your_branch_name
```